# Is there any way to send signal after focus on timeout in input field

Tags: qt, connect, signals-slots

I have got a similar situation, when I use 'autofocus' on any input field then with the below signal I'm able to bring up the keyboard :

```
connect(view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), SLOT(popupKeyboardOnAutoFocus(bool)));
```

where `popupKeyboardOnAutoFocus` is a function to bring up the keyboard.

Now, I'm trying to bring up the keyboard when focus is given to input field after a timeout of 30 sec, i.e., I have a button, after clicking which system waits for 30 seconds and then it gives focus to the input field.

Reference :

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>

<input type="text" id="myText" value="A text field">
<br><br><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
    document.getElementById("myText").focus();
    }, 3000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now when I try to use signal as below :

```
 connect(view, SIGNAL(focus(bool)),SLOT(popupKeyboardOnAutoFocus(bool)));
```

I'm unable to bring up the keyboard, but I can see the focus on the input field after 30sec.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your logic a bit and use this global signal :

```
void QApplication::focusChanged(QWidget *old, QWidget *new)
```

Where `old` is the widget that lost focut and `new` is the widget that just has focus.

So you need for example to allow your `popupKeyboardOnAutoFocus` to comply with that signal arguments by modofying its signature, for example, to:
`popupKeyboardOnAutoFocus(QWidget*, QWidget*, bool)`

then you can use new signal slot syntax as folows:

```
connect(app, &QApplication::focusChanged , this, &Myclass::popupKeyboardOnAutoFocus);
```

---

Alternatively, If you want to keep it simple , connect your `loadfinished()` to a new local slot with a *singleshot* **QTimer** of 30 seconds that then calls `popupKeyboardOnAutoFocus`:
something like:

```
connect(view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), SLOT(delayElmnt()));
```

and the delayElmnt() can be like this:

```
{
QTimer::singleShot(30000, this, SLOT(popupKeyboardOnAutoFocus()));
}
```

Comment: Hi,
Actually i have tried the second option which u have mentioned, but it is not working as excepted, can u please check if i'm doing it right.
In my constructor i have added below line :

connect(view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), SLOT(popupKeyboardOnAutoFocus(bool)));// Already present for my AutoFocus
connect(view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), SLOT(delayElmnt()));//Now added this for delay

AND

void CWebkitWindow::delayElmnt()
{
logAction("New try");
QTimer::singleShot(3000, this, SLOT(popupKeyboardOnAutoFocus()));
}

in logs i can see "New try" but keyboard is not coming up.

Comment: @SirKappe, you dont need this : `connect(view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), SLOT(popupKeyboardOnAutoFocus(bool)));`

Comment: @SirKappe since you can see "New try" , it means logic is working .. you need to inspect your `popupKeyboardOnAutoFocus` .. why its not bringing KB

Comment: Hi Kanan,
I have just cross checked it, by removing 
    connect(view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), SLOT(popupKeyboardOnAutoFocus(bool)));

as you said, but still same.
I think there is some issue with line :
"QTimer::singleShot(30000, this, SLOT(popupKeyboardOnAutoFocus(bool)));" because though that line is being executed, "popupKeyboardOnAutoFocus" function is not called..

Comment: @SirKappe, do you class inherit QOBJECT ?

Comment: @SirKappe, when you call a SLOT in this way , that SLOT need not have any arguments, you don't need to pass `bool` anymore to that SLOT, it should be `popupKeyboardOnAutoFocus()`

Comment: @SirKappe, So modify its signature to take NO arguments, OR alternatively try: `QTimer::singleShot(30000, this, SLOT(popupKeyboardOnAutoFocus(true)));`

Comment: I observed one thing, i used same syntax of QTimer to call another function which i just wrote and just added log inside that:
QTimer::singleShot(30000, this, SLOT(sample()));
and "sample" function is getting called.

Comment: except when i try to call my "popupKeyboardOnAutoFocus" as u mentioned :
QTimer::singleShot(30000, this, SLOT(popupKeyboardOnAutoFocus(true)));

this function is not getting called.

Comment: Actually, if the function that i call via SLOT has no arguments, then that function will be called, if it has any then i'm unable to call such function, thats my observation.
Please comment.

Comment: @SirKappe, this is what I mentioned in my comments. Did you get it working now?

Comment: Hi Kanan,
Actually with QTimer i can get my keyboard up after certain time, but that does not full fill my concern.
i need to bring the keyboard up once input field gets focus after certain timeout (time out can be anything at runtime, not just hard coded value which i give in QTimer )

Comment: ideal scenario is : i have an application, with one button and one input field.
Once we load application and click that button, after certain timeout (time is set in application and we are not aware of it) focus is given to input field.

At this point exactly when input gets focus, i'm supposed to bring up the keyboard.

Comment: So, i need a mechanism to emit a signal once input gets focus so that i can make use of that signal and call necessary SLOT function which brings up the keyboard.
Or/And i'm open for any other suggestions.